# Is the Python 3.x signal library for Windows incomplete?

Tags: python

I went to write a system script using 3.0 and found the SIGALRM signal and signal.alarm() call missing amongst many others on the Windows deployment. Does anyone know why these are missing? Below is a dir() of the 2.5 vs 3.0 signal packages on windows. I haven't found any 3.0 docs yet mentioning that this was moved

EDIT: signals **do** work in python25 on windows, they were removed in 3.0. I should reword my request as 'where did they go or get turned into' or is the windows 3.0 release just not complete yet?

```
python25> python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, May 18 2007, 16:56:43)
[GCC 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import signal
>>> dir(signal)
['NSIG', 'SIGABRT', 'SIGALRM', 'SIGBUS', 'SIGCHLD', 'SIGCLD',
'SIGCONT', 'SIGEMT', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGHUP', 'SIGILL', 'SIGINT ', 'SIGIO',
'SIGKILL', 'SIGPIPE', 'SIGPOLL', 'SIGPROF', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGRTMAX',
'SIGRTMIN', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGSTOP', 'SIGSYS ', 'SIGTERM', 'SIGTRAP',
'SIGTSTP', 'SIGTTIN', 'SIGTTOU', 'SIGURG', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGUSR2',
'SIGVTALRM', 'SIGWINCH', 'SIGX CPU', 'SIGXFSZ', 'SIG_DFL', 'SIG_IGN',
'__doc__', '__name__', 'alarm', 'default_int_handler', 'getsignal',
'pause', 'sig nal']

>>> exit()
python25> cd ../python31
python31> python
Python 3.1.1 (r311:74483, Aug 17 2009, 17:02:12) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import signal
>>> dir(signal)
['NSIG', 'SIGABRT', 'SIGBREAK', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGILL', 'SIGINT',
'SIGSEGV', 'SIGTERM', 'SIG_DFL', 'SIG_IGN', '__doc__', '__ name__',
'__package__', 'default_int_handler', 'getsignal', 'set_wakeup_fd',
'signal']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are running your 2.5 in cygwin, which is probably the reason that it shows up there.

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, May 18 2007, 16:56:43)
[GCC 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)] on cygwin
```

In my 2.5 for win32 it looks just like in your 3.1:

```
Python 2.5 (r25:51908, Sep 19 2006, 09:52:17) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import signal
>>> dir(signal)
['NSIG', 'SIGABRT', 'SIGBREAK', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGILL', 'SIGINT', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGTERM', 'SIG_DFL', 'SIG_IGN', '__doc__', '__
name__', 'default_int_handler', 'getsignal', 'signal']
```

Comment: A sincere DOHH! it was just staring me right in the face. I've been using cygwin for so long it's like it's part of windows for me. FYI I checked ActiveState's implementation to see if they'd gone the extra mile and sadly no, they haven't.

Answer (score 3):

Windows is *NOT* posix compliant OS so it does not have all signals - my guess is that on 3.0 the missing signals do not show up there any longer.

Comment: with out getting into a discussion about just how posix compliant Windows is, the fact that python2.5 has the signals and they work would perhaps indicate that the reason they are missing in 3.0 is due to some other decision criteria, NO?

Comment: Good point, Luckily, truppos answer points to the correct answer. So the signals do work under cygwin (but jottos' 3.0 is Windows native, not cygwin)